# How to create 3D video from two separate stereo images?

Tags: video, 3d

I have two images that form a stereo pair. I'd like to view this in 3D on a [Samsung 3D television](http://www.samsung.com/hu/consumer/televisions/televisions/plazma-tv/PS51D8000FSXXH). I was looking for such a software but did not find anything exactly for this task. My question is: how could I put this togedher? What if I make a video that changes the two images frame-by-frame in 25 fps? Is 3d avi supposed to work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sony Vegas. It can merge the stereo inputs and renders the output file as the format you need.

Comment: While this does answer the question, could you expand it a bit with more information about how this is accomplished in Vegas?

Answer (score 2):

For creating a 3d image (from two jpeg images), this piece of software works pretty well:

http://stereo.jpn.org/eng/stphmkr/

Creating a full 3d video is a bit more difficult, so I'm not sure if I can help you there.

Answer (score 1):

I recommended to use the Dashwood Stereo3D Toolbox (link: http://www.dashwood3d.com/stereo3dtoolbox.php).

I use it for convert SBS to TaB and adjust the 3D effect with Final Cut, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the gopro studio that can create a 3d video using a proprietary codec as output ( hold the 2 video stream synchronized). After that you can use more traditionnal editor that recognize the codec (need to be installed on windows) and make you final video (including most of video modification) and export in several 3d format (anaglyphe, SBS, ...). In fact this is the codec manager that hold the 3D until export.

The main problem (not tested because i use footage from gopro) is that gopro studion need to recognize your 2 video stream as source.